# How to have Django insert a sequence value into an Oracle table?

Tags: python, django, oracle

How can I instruct Django to call `nextval` on a sequence for a given model's field?

I realize that I can make a trigger in the DB:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON foo FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT foo_id_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :new.foo_id FROM dual;
END;
```

However I'm curious if Django can do it via configuration like MySQL and autoincrement.

I didn't see anything specified in the [Django Oracle notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#oracle-notes).

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12c has introduced two new features which relates to mysql autoincrement.

**Default values using sequence**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq;

CREATE TABLE t (
  x number default seq.nextval, /*-- no need for a trigger to autoincrement */.
  y varchar2(10)
);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF50946

**Identity columns**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  x number generated by default on null as identity,
  y varchar2(10)
);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402